# How to extract relational data from XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

I'm new to XML world. I'm having a problem with XML data type in SQL Server 2005.
I've a stored procedure that expects XML parameter. The value of the parameter as given below...

```
DECLARE @productIds xml

SET @productIds =
    '<ROOT>
       <AGENTLIST>
         <AGENT>
           <HOSTAPPLICATIONRECORDKEY>GRI</HOSTAPPLICATIONRECORDKEY>
           <BROKERID>02h21a0539</BROKERID>
           <BROKERSHARE>25</BROKERSHARE>
           <BROKERSTATE>AK</BROKERSTATE>
           <CARRIERCODE>GRIC</CARRIERCODE>
           <PLANCODE>EP02</PLANCODE>
           <COVERAGECODES>
               <COVERAGECODE>TL50IM06</COVERAGECODE>
               <COVERAGECODE>TL50IM10</COVERAGECODE>
           </COVERAGECODES>
           <SPLITBROKERID1>2</SPLITBROKERID1>
           <SPLITBROKERSHARE1>25</SPLITBROKERSHARE1>
           <SPLITBROKERID2></SPLITBROKERID2>
           <SPLITBROKERSHARE2>25</SPLITBROKERSHARE2>
           <SPLITBROKERID3></SPLITBROKERID3>
           <SPLITBROKERSHARE3>25</SPLITBROKERSHARE3>
           <APPSIGNEDDATE>7/31/2009</APPSIGNEDDATE>
         </AGENT>
         <AGENT>
           <HOSTAPPLICATIONRECORDKEY>GRI</HOSTAPPLICATIONRECORDKEY>
           <BROKERID>02h21a0538</BROKERID>
           <BROKERSHARE>25</BROKERSHARE>
           <BROKERSTATE>AK</BROKERSTATE>
           <CARRIERCODE>GRIC</CARRIERCODE>
           <PLANCODE>EP02</PLANCODE>
           <COVERAGECODES>
               <COVERAGECODE>TL50IM07</COVERAGECODE>
               <COVERAGECODE>TL50IM11</COVERAGECODE>
           </COVERAGECODES>
           <SPLITBROKERID1>2</SPLITBROKERID1>
           <SPLITBROKERSHARE1>25</SPLITBROKERSHARE1>
           <SPLITBROKERID2></SPLITBROKERID2>
           <SPLITBROKERSHARE2>25</SPLITBROKERSHARE2>
           <SPLITBROKERID3></SPLITBROKERID3>
           <SPLITBROKERSHARE3>25</SPLITBROKERSHARE3>
           <APPSIGNEDDATE>7/31/2009</APPSIGNEDDATE>
         </AGENT>
       </AGENTLIST>
     </ROOT>'
```

My stored procedure should return all Broker IDs and their corresponding Coverage Code(s) for each of the Broker...

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: This doesn't look like xml to me, so it would seem that you may want to start earlier in learning this. This page may be a good start for you.
http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3531196

Comment: The XML tags may have gotten stripped out in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

How does this work for you??

```
SELECT 
    PID.NDS.value('(BROKERID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'BrokerID',
    CCS.CC.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'CoverageID'
FROM
    @productIds.nodes('/ROOT/AGENTLIST/AGENT') AS PID(NDS)
CROSS APPLY
    PID.NDS.nodes('COVERAGECODES/COVERAGECODE') AS CCS(CC)
```

I get a result of:

```
BrokerID    CoverageID
02h21a0539  TL50IM06
02h21a0539  TL50IM10
02h21a0538  TL50IM07
02h21a0538  TL50IM11
```

Is that what you're looking for??

The best intro to this XML "trickery" in SQL Server 2005 and up can be found in this article "[SQL Server 2005 XQuery and XML-DML](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/050803.htm)" by Alex Homer.

Marc